# Why my mutiple animated objects are not displayed by my code WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am webGL beginner and i have to display animated multiple objects. I have written the code. It runs without error. I mean it prints all the alert test cases in start() function until `alert("I am executed6");` but still it displays nothing in browser.

What i want is to display rectangles using two triangle with animation. But it not at all display the rectangles.

My full code is :

```js
var gl;
function initGL()
{
    // Get A WebGL context
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
    if (!gl)
    {              
         return;
    }           
}
var positionLocation;
var resolutionLocation;
var colorLocation;
var translationLocation;
var rotationLocation;
var translation = [50, 50];
var rotation = [0, 1];
var angle = 0;
function initShaders()
{
    // setup GLSL program
    vertexShader = document.getElementById("2d-vertex-shader").firstChild.nodeValue;
   // vertexShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "2d-vertex-shader");
    fragmentShader = document.getElementById("2d-fragment-shader").firstChild.nodeValue;
   // fragmentShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "2d-fragment-shader");
    program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    gl.useProgram(program);
   
    // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
    positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");

    // lookup uniforms
    resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
    colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
    translationLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_translation");
    rotationLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_rotation");

    // set the resolution
    gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
function createProgram(gl,vertexShader, fragmentShader)
{
    var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vs, vertexShader);
    gl.compileShader(vs);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vs));
    //////
    var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(fs, fragmentShader);
    gl.compileShader(fs);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fs));
    program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, vs);
    gl.attachShader(program, fs);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS))
        alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
}
function initBuffers()
{
    // Create a buffer.
    var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // Set Geometry.
    setGeometry(gl);
}

function setColor(red, green, blue)
{
    gl.uniform4f(colorLocation, red, green, blue, 1);
}
// Draw the scene.
function drawScene()
{
    // Clear the canvas.
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set the translation.
    gl.uniform2fv(translationLocation, translation);
    // Set the rotation.
    gl.uniform2fv(rotationLocation, rotation);

    // Draw the geometry.
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}


// Fill the buffer with the values that define a letter 'F'.
function setGeometry(gl)
{
    var size1 = 0.5;
    /*Assume size1 is declared*/
    var vertices = [
         -size1 / 2, -size1 / 2,
         -size1 / 2, size1 / 2,
         size1 / 2, size1 / 2,
         size1 / 2, size1 / 2,
         size1 / 2, -size1 / 2,
         -size1 / 2, -size1 / 2];
    gl.bufferData(
       gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
       new Float32Array(vertices),
       gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}
function animate()
{
    translation[0] += 0.01;
    translation[1] += 0.01;
    angle += 0.01;
    rotation[0] = Math.cos(angle);
    rotation[1] = Math.sin(angle);
}
function tick()
{
   // requestAnimFrame(tick);
    drawScene();
    animate();
}
function start()
{
    alert("I am executed1");
    initGL();
    alert("I am executed2");
    initShaders();
    alert("I am executed3");
    initBuffers();
    alert("I am executed4");
    setColor(0.2, 0.5, 0.5);
    alert("I am executed5");
    tick();
    alert("I am executed6"); //All are executed, so no error in code
}
start();
```

```html
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec2 a_position;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_translation;
uniform vec2 u_rotation;
void main() 
{
  vec2 rotatedPosition = vec2(
  a_position.x * u_rotation.y + a_position.y * u_rotation.x,
  a_position.y * u_rotation.y - a_position.x * u_rotation.x);
  
  // Add in the translation.
  vec2 position = rotatedPosition + u_translation;
  
  // convert the position from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
  vec2 zeroToOne = position / u_resolution;
  
  // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
  vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
  
  // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
  vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
  
  gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace, 0, 1);
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  precision mediump float;

  uniform vec4 u_color;

  void main()
  {
    gl_FragColor = u_color;
  }
</script>
<div style="text-align: center">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
</div>
```

What is the problem with this code ? Is there any logical error. How to display animated objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when I run your code and I check the Web Console/Error Console, whatever it's called in your browser of choice I get these errors

```
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: getAttribLocation: no object or object deleted
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: getUniformLocation: no object or object deleted
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: getUniformLocation: no object or object deleted
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: getUniformLocation: no object or object deleted
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: getUniformLocation: no object or object deleted
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: enableVertexAttribArray: index out of range
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: vertexAttribPointer: index out of range
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: no valid shader program in use
```

Looking at the code the first problem I see is that you're using lots of global variables. The specific reason for all those errors is you have this line

```
program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);
```

But `createProgram` does not return anything so after that line `program` = `undefined` and all the parts of the code that use `program` fail.

So, adding

```
  return program;
```

to the end of `createProgram` all the errors go away.

After that the `size1` in `setGeometry` is set to 0.5 and is then divided by 2 so it's trying to draw a 1/2 a pixel. Changing it to

```
var size1 = 10;
```

and I see a 10 pixel bluish-green square get drawn.

Also note you might find using `console.log(msg)` better than `alert(msg)`. You don't have to click to see each result but you do have to open the JavaScript Console/Web Console to see the messages. In Chrome that's View->Developer->JavaScript Console. In Firefox it's Tools->Web Developer->Web Console. In Safari you first after to enable the developer menu in Safari's preferences under Safari->Preferences->Advanced->Show Develop menu in menu Bar. Once you've done that it's Develop->Show Error Console